# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Code Review breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6         25
Users destroyed                                 112          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                  20          0
User review-bans lifted early                     2          0
User banned from review                           3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           145      3,297
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               47      1,958
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        120      2,222
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               11      1,373
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                67      7,958
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              384     10,788
Tags merged                                       8          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            14          0
Tag synonyms created                             14          0
Tag highlight language set                        4          0
Revisions redacted                               15          0
Questions unprotected                             4          1
Questions reopened                              179        120
Questions protected                              69         39
Questions migrated                               15          3
Questions merged                                  8          0
Questions flagged⁴                               46      3,661
Questions closed                              2,158      2,638
Question flags handled⁴                         858      2,849
Posts unlocked                                    6         14
Posts undeleted                                  38        307
Posts locked                                     19        229
Posts deleted⁵                                1,404      6,291
Posts bumped                                      0      3,793
Escalations to the CM team                       45          0
Comments undeleted                              108          0
Comments flagged                                 17      2,611
Comments deleted⁶                             6,385      6,014
Comment flags handled                         1,404      1,224
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                  62      2,333
Answer flags handled                          1,852        543
All comments on a post moved to chat             18          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...