# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Code Review over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                   7         26
Users destroyed³                                  40          0
Users deleted                                      1          0
Users contacted                                   16          0
User suspensions lifted early                      1          0
User banned from review                            1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue             53      3,231
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                 7      1,130
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         120      1,819
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                 3        803
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                  2      6,703
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               119      9,911
Tags merged                                        8          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              8          0
Tag synonyms created                               8          0
Revisions redacted                                15          0
Questions reopened                                50         74
Questions protected                               63         33
Questions migrated                                12         13
Questions merged                                   2          0
Questions flagged⁵                                17      2,710
Questions closed                                 717      2,573
Question flags handled⁵                          481      2,246
Posts unlocked                                     6         12
Posts undeleted                                   19        260
Posts locked                                      16        150
Posts deleted⁶                                   854      4,979
Posts bumped                                       0      1,252
Escalations to the Community Manager team          9          0
Comments undeleted                                58          0
Comments flagged                                  25      3,295
Comments deleted⁷                              3,309      6,943
Comment flags handled                          1,349      1,971
Answers flagged                                   65      1,898
Answer flags handled                           1,574        391
All comments on a post moved to chat              13          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: `Users suspended/destroyed/deleted` can you please break these numbers down into *related/unrelated to the Monica insubordination*?

Comment: @greybeard I don't think that's possible, but why would you want that in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

For convenience, here is the change compared to [last year](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/2018-a-year-in-moderation):

```
                                         Moderators  Community
Action                                                        
All comments on a post moved to chat             -5          0
Answer flags handled                           -278       -152
Answers flagged                                   3       -435
Bounties canceled                                -1          0
Comment flags handled                           -55        747
Comments deleted                              -3076        929
Comments flagged                                  8        684
Comments undeleted                              -50          0
Escalations to the CM team                      -36          0
Posts bumped                                      0      -2541
Posts deleted                                  -550      -1312
Posts locked                                     -3        -79
Posts undeleted                                 -19        -47
Posts unlocked                                    0         -2
Question flags handled                         -377       -603
Questions closed                              -1441        -65
Questions flagged                               -29       -951
Questions merged                                 -6          0
Questions migrated                               -3         10
Questions protected                              -6         -6
Questions reopened                             -129        -46
Questions unprotected                            -4         -1
Revisions redacted                                0          0
Tag highlight language set                       -4          0
Tag synonyms created                             -6          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            -6          0
Tags merged                                       0          0
Tasks reviewed: Close Votes queue              -265       -877
Tasks reviewed: First Post queue                -65      -1255
Tasks reviewed: Late Answer queue                -8       -570
Tasks reviewed: Low Quality Posts queue           0       -403
Tasks reviewed: Reopen Vote queue               -40       -828
Tasks reviewed: Suggested Edit queue            -92        -66
User banned from review                          -2          0
User review-bans lifted early                    -2          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Users contacted                                  -4          0
Users deleted                                     0          0
Users destroyed                                 -72          0
Users suspended                                   1          1
```

It seems like overall activity has been going down.

Comment: Considering the amount of [questions per week](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1019088/questions-per-week#graph) has been going down as well and the [ratios have been stable](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/166314/site-activity-ratios?Weeks=104#graph), the numbers in this answer are not surprising.